# elpy can't find new python version (upgraded from 3.9 to 3.11)

Tags: python, elpy

I've upgraded from python 3.9 to 3.11 on my windows machine (on that I don't have admin rights). I used emacs (elpy) before to manage my python projects. Unfortunately, after the upgrade it seems elpy can't find the new interpreter. It still looks for python 3.9 although the virtualenv rebuild with 3.11

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 28.1
Elpy..............: Not found (Python), 1.35.0 (Emacs Lisp)
Virtualenv........: srv (c:/Users/ca/srv/)
Interactive Python: ipython 8.13.1 (c:/Users/ca/srv/Scripts/ipython.exe)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (c:/Users/ca/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: c:/Windows/py.exe nil (c:/Windows/py.exe)
 Jedi.............: Not found
 Autopep8.........: Not found
 Yapf.............: Not found
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: Not found (flake8)
```

However, if I activate the virtualenv in the prompt shell I can start python 3.11 correctly.

```
(srv) C:\Users\ca>ipython
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: quit()
```

Happy to provide any other information (like init.el etc) that might help to resolve the problem